# Are friend-removals bidirectional?

Tags: steam

When I remove a friend from my friend list in steam, am I also removed from his friend list or can he still see when I come online, enter a game and so on?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you remove a friend you will also be removed from their list:

[Steam friend removal discussion](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1712483)

You can block someone and you will then appear 'Offline' to them at all times (they then cannot post on your profile either)